# Drag a not selected item from list with an already selected item does not come into drag info on mouse down event?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

In WPF ItemsControl, dragging an item (not selected) with an already selected item with control key pressed, does not give the clicked item into selected items list of the items control. Therefor the second item (which wasn't selected but dragged) never gets dropped as it is not in the selected list of items control. 
The DragInfo object is being created on drag source's mouse left button down event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the selected item, use InputHitTest in the MouseDown event to find the element that was clicked, and use this element's DataContext to create the DragInfo object.

Comment: This works fine for me. I've added a list property to hold all dragged items. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can handle `OnPreviewMouseleftButtonDown` event and add the dragged (but not selected) item to `SelectedItems`.